# Changes in wsdl.xml file in Magento SOAP V2

Tags: soap, magento

I have a problem, that whenever I make changes to my custom API extension WSDL file, the changes are not visible immediately. It takes a day or two for them to appear. I have tried to clear the Magento `tmp` directory, but there is nothing to be cleared. Also, I have tried restarting my local apache server, and cleaning its `/tmp` directories, from where I make API calls, but no help.

Does anyone have idea why is this, and how it can be corrected? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Just a friendly note, you'll get more (and better) responses to your questions when you accept answers on previous questions you've asked.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Joseph. I have allready accepted some answers that realy worked for me. i will check the others too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get changes for the various xml files to take effect in a more timely manner you have to clear the magento cache. It can be found in $magentoinstall/var/cache

When you do that it forces magento to reprocess all the config and your change should appear right away.

I hear tell you can use the magento admin panel to accomplish this as well

Go to System -> Cache Management

Click on “select all” in the upper left corner
Under “action” click on “refresh” and click submit 
Then click on these buttons:
Flush Magento Cache
Flush Cache Storage

I've never used the 2nd method.  See here for more information.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_cache/index

Comment: I am not getting option of "select all" Please guide me.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching this  I put the wrong path in the origional answer. It has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cache from System -> Cache Management seems to have 0 affect on WSDL.

While testing you can prevent Mage from caching WSDL with this code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://somewhere.com/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
```

Answer (score 0):

**On the server side** you can disable Magento Wsdl cache at System->Configurations->Services->Magento Core API->Enable WSDL Cache.

Maybe you should remove all files from var/cache/ folder.

---

**On the client side** (api client) you can simply add

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```

to avoid SoapClient lib caching.